# Why is this resistor connected in such way?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, bias

Why is the R2 resistor connected to bias instead of ground? As far as I know, only one of the op-amp's inputs has to be biased, so why such configuration? Also, how does this affect the gain?

[image]

Edit #1: Vcc here is 5V.

Edit #2:

R2 connected as shown above:
[image]

R2 in series with a 10uF cap connected to ground:
[image]

Comment: Since you have the simulation setup already run it with and without

Comment: @PlasmaHH without it the passband goes from ~700Hz to 1MHz+, so it doesn't function properly anymore. I don't understand why this happens as in my point of view the circuit with R2 being grounded is already biased.

Comment: 1) What if R2 is **not** needed for DC biasing (it isn't R1, R3 and R4 take care of this). 2) having R2, 150 ohms connected to a point which has a much higher impedance (to ground) is silly, R2 disturbs the Vdd/2 you make with R3 and R4. 3) remove the connection at the left of R2 and connect it via 10 uF capacitor in series to **ground**. Again I suspect you're just "trying things" without understanding what you're doing. If you want to work with (change, simulate) circuits you **must** understand them. "Trying stuff" is a pointless exercise.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I do try to understand them. It looks to me that there will be a bias coming through R2, which is what confuses me. I know that you can ground R2 with a cap connected in series to it but then it gives different results. What I am trying to say is that I have never seen this before and it looks unusual to me, hence why I am asking for someone to put it in a different perspective for me.

Comment: There are some tips to help you better understand that circuit: use transient analysis without and with AC signal coming into your scheme and look at the input/output voltage. Then repeat the same simulation, but with different R3/R4 (47k/100k for example) ratio and notice output voltage offset.

Comment: @Vadimchik I am going to try that, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gain of the amplifier (about 670) and the DC offset that would result from having R2 return to the negative supply, would have the unfortunate
effect of clipping the output signal.   Output (maximum) with a 5V supply 
is maybe 4V, and that maximum output voltage would at most only drive
the negative input to $$V_{input} = 4V \times {150\over {100k + 150}} = 0.06 V$$

The bias potential at the (-) input is some 2.44V lower than this voltage applied at the (+) input.  The op amp will be saturated (with the output driven high) 
until that (+) input pin is driven lower than 60 millivolts...
The op amp, while saturated, offers no voltage gain, of course.

It is confusing to refer to the negative power pin of the amplifier
as 'ground' unless small signals hover about that potential.    For the purposes of this circuit, small signal input (and output) of the amplifier are most easily visualized as being near the R1-R2-R3-R4
common junction, the 'bias' point.   Signal generator and load are
capacitor decoupled, their 'ground' point is useless as a DC bias for
the LM324 signal.

Answer (score 2):

If your Opamp have negative power supply tied to the ground, you want to keep signal on it's inputs not lower, than GND and not higher than Vcc. That is what your circuit does - it introduces bias to AC sine wave to keep it in its range. Circuit, you drawn will probably reduce it's gain, because instead of ground R2 is connected to voltage divider R3-R4(which have too high output impedance) and your AC source is also connected to that divider through C2-R1. So part of your AC signal will transform to common-mode signal(because of R1) on Opamp inputs. In other words all that circuitry helps you to "emulate" Opamp powered with negative supply, and R3/R4 divider introduces some "virtual ground" (not to be confused with negative input in inverting amplifier). You have very high gain and with R2 connected to the ground you would have Opamp output always at high rail voltage (VCC - 0.7 or something about that), because you will amplify your signal on positive input with respect to ground, having Vcc/2 offset on your positive input. If you want to connect R2 to ground and keep gain than high, you should chose resistors in your voltage divider very carefully with respect to AC amplitude, which is slightly harder.

To reduce that bias circuitry influence on your circuit gain you may want to:

1. Use lower values of R3 and R4 resistors. It is better to have them 10 or more times lower, than R1.
2. Use separate voltage divider for R2. That may lead to some problems, connected with resistance tolerance of the real parts.

BTW you better check voltage on your C2 cap - maybe it should be replaced with non-polarized.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Could you please elaborate a bit on this part "and R3/R4 divider introduces some "virtual ground"?

Comment: @Hypomania As I mentioned, because R3/R4 voltage divider have low output impedance, your AC source will also infulence voltage on it's output. Voltage drop on node common for R1/R2/R3/R4 will have the same phase as on the positive input, but the magnitude will be much lower - you get tiny common-mode signal. That voltage drop goes to the feedback circuit and gets subtracted from voltage on positive input which is a signal, you want to amplify.

Comment: Did you mean to say "low" output impedance? Because in your answer you said it was too high?

Comment: I misspelled. Output impedance of the divider, consisting of two 100k resistors can't be low - it is high.